# Drools 6.50 Error when using JDK 1.8

Tags: compiler-errors, drools

I am getting a error when running drools-core 6.5.0.Final with a simple spring configuration in mule. I am using spring 4.3.5.Final and JDK 1.8. I am getting an error
 org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: NoSuchFieldError: COMPILER_OPT_ALLOW_RESOLVE_INNERCLASSES_WITH_DOTNOTATION
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:205. It fails when initializing and verifying the KieContainer. Please note that I unzipped the archive and there are not conflicting jars in the archive. I only found 2 drools specific jars, drools-core and drools-decisiontables, both version 6.5.0.Final. Also, there are no duplicate jars for the remaining dependencies. The pom only has all spring framework 4.3.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.3.

```
  kieContainer = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();

  LOG.info(kieContainer.verify().getMessages().toString());
```

I am processing a Excel spreadsheet decision table.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc=
       "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.8.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
         http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
        <spring:beans>
            <spring:bean id="letter" name="letter" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
                    <spring:constructor-arg name="path" value="com/xyz/db-config.xml"/>
            </spring:bean>
        <spring:bean id="stylusConfiguration"  name="stylusConfiguration" class="com.xyz.Talent">
                <spring:property name="config">
                    <spring:map>
                        <spring:entry key="member" value-ref="letter"/>
                    </spring:map>
                </spring:property>
            </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="builderFactory" name="builderFactory" class="com.xyz.BuilderFactory" 
        factory-method="newInstance"/>
        <spring:bean id="translator" name="translator" class="com.xyz.TranslatorConfigurator">
            <spring:property name="factory" ref="builderFactory"/>
            <spring:property name="stylus" ref="stylusConfiguration"/>
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="eLander" name="eLander"   class="com.xyz.transformers.TranslatorConfigurer">
           <spring:property name="translator" ref="translator"/>
        </spring:bean>

        </spring:beans>
```

I have searched for a reason but found no answers. The problem seems to be with the mvel library but I don't know what might be triggering it. Please help!

```
        </mule>
```

I can see from the stacktrace the problem is here in a spring method I implement
it fails at the LOG.info below

```
     @Override
 public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    kieContainer = ...;

        LOG.info(kieContainer.verify().getMessages().toString());
    try {


                  this.builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();

             } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
```

Here are the dependencies in my pom:

```
                             <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
                <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

                   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
         <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
         <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
              <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
              <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>



          </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the classloader. I did the following t solve the issue:

```
 KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        kieContainer = ks.newKieClasspathContainer(getClass    ().getClassLoader());
```